# Ubuntu 18 battery is charging but not increasing

Tags: 18.04, power-management, laptop, battery

I am using ubuntu 18 on a Razor Blade 15 laptop.

Yesterday I used the laptop without AC, and the battery was used up and the laptop shut down.

After I plugged in the AC charger, I could boot the laptop and enters into the system as usual, however, there are several issues:

1. the battery is shown being charged, but the percentage never increased:
   [image: power]

[image: statistics]

2. Once I unplug the AC charger, the laptop would shut down immeidiate.

I suspect it is because the *battery profile* is locked in with some outdated file, which does not reflect the true situation of the battery?

Updated. I shutdown the laptop and plugged in AC adaptor for 10 min. The laptop still not charged.

Comment: Obviously the battery is dead.

Comment: Try shutting down the laptop completely and charging it when it's off (and the OS has nothing to do with charging). If it still won't charge, it's either a BIOS issue or a hardware issue. If it does charge, update your question with that info.

Comment: @Esther
I tried charging with the OS shut down. The stats still not increasing.

Why it must be BIOS issue or hardware issue in this case? can it be the case the ubuntu is not reading the right file when showing the stats?

Comment: @GeauxEric you have a hardware issue. Most likely your battery/charging circuit is dead.

Comment: The battery is independent of the operating system. It communicates with BIOS and the BIOS communicates with the OS.  I agree with Pilot6 and Esther: get a replacement battery as it is more than likely broken